# Solution of $f(x)=0.5 \cdot x^{(T)}Ax-b^T \cdot x+c$

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I'm trying to prove that $f(x)=0.5 \cdot x^{(T)}Ax-b^T \cdot x+c$,given that $A$ is symmetric positive-definite has only one minimum.
I've found the derivative is $f'(x)=Ax-b$, and in order to find the minimum we need to find the solution of $Ax=b$. We does $Ax=b$ have only one solution given that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite?

I'd be grateful for any explanation , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis that $A$ is symmetric positive definite means that $v^TAv > 0$ for every $v \ne 0$; this in turn implies $\ker A = \{0\}$, for if $0 \ne w \in \ker A$, $w^TAw = w^T(0) = 0$, contradicting the definiteness of $A$.  $\ker A = \{0\}$ implies in turn that $A$ is nonsingular, hence $A^{-1}$ exists.  Thus $Ax = b$ implies $x = A^{-1}b$ and that such $x$ is the unique solution.   And that is why.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Cool answer given by a cool person. Thanks !

Comment: @itamar:  What a nice thing to say!  A *baruch* upon you for the kind words.  And thanks for the "acceptance"!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $A$ is symmetric positive definite, what can you say about its eigenvalues and diagonalization? Are any of them $0$?